# SDL_CreateWindow (SDL2.0.3) sometimes will never finish

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdl-2

I've set up a separate thread to handle screen refreshes on a game port.  This allows me to concentrate on just updating the memory buffer I use for the main game with simple block graphics.  All I have to worry about is changing what is where, the rendering thread will automatically update the display texture in the background.  It works great (after adding in a delay between rendering loops.)  The problem is that on seemingly random occasions, the SDL_CreateWindow call will never return.  It doesn't give an error, it just sits there doing nothing.  The InitVideo section of the thread is:

```
const HWND desk = GetDesktopWindow();
RECT dsize;
FILE *cfile;
int count1, count2;

printf("Reading font file\r\n");
fopen_s(&cfile,"character.dat","rb");
for(count1 = 0; count1 < 128; count1++)
    for(count2 = 0; count2 < 8; count2++)
        chROM[count1][count2] = (unsigned char)fgetc(cfile);
fclose(cfile);
printf("Font data read\r\n");

GetWindowRect(desk,&dsize);
if (fullscreen) {
    width = dsize.right;
    height = dsize.bottom;
} else {
    height = (int)(dsize.bottom * .85);
    if (((height * 6) / 5) > dsize.right) {
        width = (int)(dsize.right * .85);
        height = (int)((width * 5) / 6);
    } else width = (int)((height * 6) / 5);
}

printf("Initializing SDL\r\n");
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) != 0) {
    printf("SDL Initialization failed\r\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    exit(-1);
}

printf("Creating Window\r\n");
if (fullscreen) 
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Ultima: Escape from Mount Drash!!",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED \
            ,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,0,0,SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP |     SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
else screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Ultima: Escape from Mount Drash",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED \
            ,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if(!screen) {printf("Failed to create screen\r\n");Sleep(2000);exit(-1);}
printf("Screen Created\r\n");
```

The main intro point code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char lv$[10];
    int count;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    _beginthread(Video, 0, NULL);
    Sleep(5000);
```

The Sleep command is to give the video time to initialize and open up.  It's just a black screen for a few seconds after it's up and running, but I can live with that.  The first screen is just an information screen anyways.  If I happen to but something into the buffer before the screen opens up and starts rendering, it shouldn't be a problem.  It's filled with zeroes on creation anyway (in the header - global variable so both the render & main threads can access it.)

The thing is, about 8 times out of 10, the window will never open.  The output stops at "Creating Window" and never gets anything else.  I've waited up to 30 minutes with nothing.  I have to force exit (through windows.)  I cannot figure out any sort of pattern.  I'll load the game once without issue, then the next five times (with Visual Studio open or closed,) it will fail.  Then it will succeed the next 10 times, then fail 20 times, etc...  When it does work, it works great, without any problems or crashes (so far.)  Going through debug mode (Visual C++ 2010) gets to that point, and just sits there.  No error messages, no nothing.  I hit F11 (step into,) and it just sits there.  It doesn't go on, it doesn't go in.

I tried to post a question on the SDL forum, but apparently it's locked out so that I can't post new messages.  And, yes, I did validate my account with the e-mail.

Comment: does sdl allow you to update the view from a different thread than the main thread? usually the main thread is allowed to draw on screen and the logic is moved to different threads

Comment: SDL was never designed in a thread safe way and Sam has openly admitted this. The thread that created the main window is the only thread that can/should access it (including e.g. handling events). This is more of a limitation of the underlying APIs from what I have seen.

Comment: Everything SDL is handled in one thread.  All I do outside the thread is alter a buffer (an array actually.)  The render thread reads the array, converts it to ARGB pixels, updates the texture, renders it, waits a brief moment, then repeats.  It also polls the events and puts the results in a structure that I can read from the main thread, but I haven't finished writing that code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly in response to all the comments, but also has the answer to my original problem.  Comments just don't give me the space to say everything that needs saying here.

First, the answer, as it appears to apply to my problem.  It seems that the code I posted actually works just fine (as far as my issue goes at least.)  It seems that somehow Visual C++ got switched to "Release" mode, while I was still using the debug exe file for testing.  I don't remember changing it (or changing it back,) and never had any reason to do so.  I discovered this when I went to switch to release mode, and discovered that an exe file had already been built there (with none of the needed support files present - SDL2.dll for example.)  Going back through my archive (I periodically archive the entire project directory,) I tracked down the two points (or close,) where it switched, and this led me to the following conclusions.

1) If you are going to thread out SDL routines, then all SDL calls have to be in that thread.  Having any SDL calls outside that thread (even event polling it seems,) will lead to apparently random (and in some cases quite illogical,) errors.  For example, for some reason having SDL calls in separate threads caused access violation faults when I closed a file stream (my log file in this case.)  The fclose(lfile); call kept causing an error, even though it is in no way related to SDL.

2) When you start the SDL thread, make sure you wait for it to finish initializing before continuing with the main thread.  If the wrong thing is going on in your main thread when the SDL thread is creating something it might lock up at that point for some reason.  The SDL_CreateWindow() function seems to be the only culprit, but I cannot say that for sure.  In my final code, I use a global Boolean variable for this instead of a delay.  Basically I create the variable (bool SDLRunning;) and set it to false.  I then start the SDL thread (_beginthread(Video, 0, NULL);).  Next I set up a loop that just watches the variable (while (!SDLRunning) Sleep(10);).  Finally, when the SDL thread is finished initializing everything, and is doing nothing but its function loop, it sets the variable to true to let my main thread know it's safe to continue.

So far, and I'm pretty much finished now, I have had no other problems of any sort (other than your standard bugs that creep into any program.)  It runs smoothly now.  I've had to go in and tweak things now and again, but that's it (the timing is a bit off here, forgot to clear a variable there, that sort of thing.)

Now, in answer to some of the comments.  The rendering of the video was threaded out because it actually made programming the game code itself easier.  The original code was designed around a system that didn't require you to program video rendering.  So, it used print statements and memory addresses for graphics.  Instead of having to manually add in render calls, I just use an array to represent to "graphics ram" of the original system.  Then when I convert the hundreds of lines of the original code that poked graphics RAM with a value, I am not forced to immediately call the render functions every time.

Also, the original game had several background tasks that depended on fairly accurate timing.  It did this by using hardware interrupts (that Microsoft in their infinite wisdom removed all access to.)  I originally tried to emulate HW interrupts in various ways, all without success.  Putting them in a separate thread (that I labeled Video only because it's heaviest load is converting and rendering the video,) with an adjustable delay time was the only method that worked right.  One of those was to change the color of a display area 7.5 times a second (15 times every 2 seconds.)  Since I had put all the color responsibility with the video function, and all things SDL (like the video functions,) have to be in the same thread, SDL needs to be in the same thread as that routine.

Finally, one of the background tasks was to play various synthesized music tunes (square waves.)  I wanted to retain the original feel of the game, so I wanted to synthesize the music as well.  I didn't want to record several wave files (the smallest of which was 253K,) to replace the 3k of data the original game used for it's music.  So, it needed careful timing beyond what any of the other tasks needed.  I also needed a sound library that could do this, but that's a separate issue (that I managed to solve despite the insults of others, or my questions being totally ignored.)

All of this I originally tried to do without any sort of interrupts (or any emulation thereof,) or creating a separate thread.  This led to real mess of complications, and a wasted month of programming.  It was this original failure of code that was practically impossible to follow (even by me, and I wrote the blasted thing,) that made me start trying to program in an interrupt routine.  I could have done this easily if I had been programming for DOS (and I'm getting a little tired of the insults many people seem to cast at everyone that wants to program something for DOS,) but Microsoft's removal of interrupt access complicated things.  In DOS, you just read an interrupt vector that triggers at a stable regularity (x times a second.)  Redirect that vector to your code.  Then make sure the last action of your interrupt code is a jump to the original vector.  Finally, when your program is exiting, restore the interrupt to its original vector.  Nice and simple.  I guess Microsoft doesn't trust programmers to know the necessity of the last two steps, but they could have at least included some way to "insert" a function (or functions,) into a pre-existing interrupt routine.

Answer (score 0):

[This forum post](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=6281&sid=370f31d4ed316c828af57fe3c3b4f2b3) is old (from before SDL2) but I don't think this part changed much. I'd advise you to move your processing loop to another thread and leave everything video and event related in the main thread, as SDL seems to not be ready for your use case, you'll achieve the same desired effect.

Also be aware that having the rendering loop detached from update loop can cause some gameplay problems (e.g, fighting games where players tend to rely on the correct "frame range" to throw an attack). You might be seeing the past frame instead of the current.

Comment: OK, it's been 100+ test runs, and the problem seems to have stopped.  I have no idea what I did (if I even did anything,) to fix the problem.  I had changed the order of things a bit, but not by much.  Before I called the main loop function with _beginthread, and it immediately called the InitVideo function.  Now, I call the InitVideo function with _beginthread, and it calls the loop (then waits for a return when I turn the thread off.)  Maybe that has something to do with it, I just don't know :(

Comment: Once I moved the entire SDL block into a single thread there hasn't been any issues of that nature.  Before that, I had unexplainable crashes and such (with no rhyme or reason I could determine.)  It was reading on SDL's problem with threading that I moved them all together (and those problems disappeared.)  Also, even with a small delay between rendering loops, it can still keep up with the speed (if you can call it that,) of gameplay.  This is a circa 1983 game I'm porting, speed isn't an issue.  If the loop can maintain 30FPS, it more than matches anything the game itself can do.

Comment: Yeah, putting SDL video and event calls on another thread other than the main thread (even if they initialize SDL) seems to be not advised, specially on systems such as Android where SDL will create other threads to make things work. Since you're porting an old game, I don't see much gains going multithread, only the complexity of it.

Comment: Also I always say this, you have to think does your program really require multi-threading as most of the time the honest answer is no and it is just an added complication that can sometime lead to worse performance if done incorrectly.